# Updating multiple entries in a unique column at once with "pure" Hibernate/JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have a table that stores tasks, and a table that stores ordered steps for that task. Steps belong to a task parent (so a task has a one-to-many relationship with a step) and each step has an "ordinal" - which step number it is. I would like the ordinal and the parent task ID to be a combined unique constraint, so for example a single Task can't ever wind up with two different steps set as "step 1", but different tasks can each have their own "step 1".

I would like to be able to update the ordinal of every step belonging to a task at the same time, so that I don't violate the unique constraint. So if I had "Step 1," "Step 2" and "Step 3" I could insert a new step at "Step 2" and shift the existing steps along to become "Step 3" and "Step 4." I'm aware that certain databases allow you to delay checking the constraints until the transaction is committed, but I would highly prefer if I could avoid anything that would require a certain database type, and do this wholly within JPA/Hibernate.

Here's a simplified version of my entities:

Task:

```
@Table
@Entity
public class Task {

    @Version
    private Long version;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Step> steps;
}
```

Step:

```
@Entity
@Table(
    uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(
            name = "UX_Step_Parent_Ordinal",
            columnNames = {"parent_id", "ordinal"})
    }
)
public class Step {

    @Version
    private Long version;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "ordinal")
    private Long ordinal;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Task parent;
}
```

So far the only way I've come up with is to first insert the new step at the end, and then dynamically generate an HQL query that looks like the following, which updates every single step in a particular task at once using a CASE:

```
UPDATE Step s
SET s.ordinal = CASE
 WHEN (s.id = 55) THEN 1
 WHEN (s.id = 58) THEN 2
 WHEN (s.id = 47) THEN 3
 WHEN (s.id = 33) THEN 4
 ... etc
 ELSE 0 END
WHERE s.parent.id = 5
```

However I'm pretty sure this requires the engine to process the query anew every single time it happens and therefore can't take advantage of things like query caching or other speedups. Is there another way to do this with Hibernate/JPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if it really solves the problem, but I think you should model the collection as a map:

```
@OneToMany
@MapKeyJoinColumn(Name="ordinal")
private Map<Long,Step> steps;
```

when you add a Step somewhere in between, it's your duty to update the entire Map.

If you still need the ordinal in the step, then you must make it readOnly:

```
@Column(nullable = false, name = "ordinal", insertable=false, updateable=false)
private Long ordinal;
```

Comment: Oh that's a good idea, any time I'm listing out the steps in a way that they'd need to be ordered I'd be accessing them through the Task entity anyway.

Comment: I was going to mark this as the accepted answer but you're right, it doesn't really answer the specific question. If nobody else has any good suggestions I'll come back and mark this as accepted in a few days though.